# Channel Parameters

Tags: channel

I'm a newbie in wireless communication.

I found one channel model and have some questions regarding its parameters

In this channel model below..

[image]

$\alpha_m,$$e^{j\varphi(k,n)}$, $\tau_m$, $\theta_m$, $\phi_m$  is complex channel gain, time delay, AoA(Angle of Arrival), AoD(Angle of Departure) Respectively.

To calculate channel $h$ how can I get these parameters?

Comment: you don't *get* them, you *give* them. These are the parameters of *your* model!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I want to give the parameters to my model, but I don't know how can I have those parameters to give the model.  In case of channel gain, can I use rayleigh or rician channel model for it?

Comment: but it's *your* model. We can't know what you want to model! You can use whatever distribution for every parameter as you want. Whether or not that model is than a good representation of what *you* want to model is a different question!

Comment: Ah-ha! now I can understand. Thank you so much!